# Can't specify a keystore file for https

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I've being pulling my hair for hours with Play (again). I'm using v2.4.6 and trying to use a custom keystore file for HTTPS access.

Si I followed the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ConfiguringHttps) :

- Added `javaOptions in run += "-Dhttp.port=9020"` in my build.sbt file
- Added `play.server.https.keyStore.path = "conf/mykeystorefile.jks` and `play.server.https.keyStore.password = "my_keystore_file_passphrase`

So then I use activator UI to launch play, as usual, and HTTPS requests do work, BUT play always generates a `generated.keystore` and uses it instead of using the one I need. And prints a warn : "Using generated key with self signed certificate for HTTPS. This should not be used in production."

If I look at Play source code, [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.6/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ssl/DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala#L57) is where the log comes from. But when reading the code, this should only happened if `play.server.https.keyStore.path` is not provided, which it is...

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I guess you are using Play in dev mode. If that's the case, I think in dev mode Play is unable to read those values before starting the application (the same problem that makes you use javaOptions to specify the port).

You can try to specify those values using system properties (`-Dplay.server.https.(...)`) or specify those options in `build.sbt`:

```
devSettings := Map(
    "play.server.http.port" -> "9020",
    "play.server.https.keyStore.path" -> "/path/to/file",
    // (...)
)
```

Note: don't know if that was a typo in your config, but I think you need to specify `https.port` also...

Comment: Yes I meant `https.port` it was a typo.

`devSettings` didn't work but adding `javaOptions in run += "-Dplay.server.https.keyStore.path=path/to/keystore"` and `javaOptions in run += "-Dplay.server.https.keyStore.password=password"` to my build.sbt did the trick. 

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

For those that really only want this in dev mode...

"You can configure extra settings for the run command in your build.sbt. These settings won’t be used when you deploy your application."

~ https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfigFile#Extra-devSettings

Ex:

```
PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq(
   "https.port" -> "9443",
   "play.server.https.keyStore.path" -> "conf/keystore.jks"
)
```